# Go throw a list of repo in a manifest file

Tags: bash, git, repo

I have a manifest file that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<manifest> 
     <remote name="origin" fetch="ssh://git@xxxxxxx.xx.:7339/xxxx/"/> 
     <default remote="origin" revision="develop" sync-j="4"/> 
     <project name="android-analytics"/> 
     <project name="android-login-lib"/> 
     <project name="android-network-lib"/> 
    <project name="android-ocr-lib" /> 
    <project name="android-xxxx"/> 
    <project name="android-resources-lib"/> 
    <project name="android-info"/> 
    <project name="android-lib"/> 
    <project name="android-styleguide"/> 
    <project name="android-test-lib"/> 
</manifest>
```

So what I want is got into each of the repository. Compare the top brach with the branch that is checked out. This is my try but it dont work. So when i find the diff I will search for a key and then if it exist write into a jira ticket.

```
env.fileName = "test.txt" 
env.TESTAR = "" 
sh '''         
echo "Link build to Jira"                                                 
kinit $SERVICE_ACCOUNT -k -t $KEYTAB_PATH 
                                                    
#fx feat/jira-test 
echo "Main branch name: ${BRANCH_NAME}"         
curl -s --negotiate --insecure -u $BITBUCKET_SERVICE_ACCOUNT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${BIT_API_URL}/projects/xxxx/repos/${REPO_NAME}/default-branch/" > main.json 

#fx develop 
TOP_BRANCH_NAME=$(jq -r '.displayId?' main.json) 
                                                    
# fx feat/jiratest 
echo "Source branch is: ${BRANCH_NAME}" 
                                                    
repo forall -c 'base=$(pwd);basename $base >> ../names.txt'                                                         
repo forall -c "git log -n 1 --pretty=%d HEAD | tr -s ',' '\\n' | grep -v HEAD | head -n1 | sed 's|m/||' | sed 's|)||' >> ../branches.txt" 
                                                    
                                                                                                            
while read file1 <&3 && read file2 <&4 
  do 
  echo "This is file1: $file1" 
  echo "This is file2: $file2" 
                                                      
  echo "Get latest commit this branch" 
  curl -s --negotiate --insecure -u $BITBUCKET_SERVICE_ACCOUNT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${BIT_API_URL}/projects/XXXX/repos/${file1}/commits?until=${file}&limit=1" > branchcommit.json 
  BRANCH_COMMIT=$(jq -r '.values[].id?' branchcommit.json) 
                                                      
  echo "Get latest commit on main branch" 
  curl -s --negotiate --insecure -u $BITBUCKET_SERVICE_ACCOUNT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${BIT_API_URL}/projects/XXXX/repos/${REPO_NAME}/commits?until=${TOP_BRANCH_NAME}&limit=1" > maincommit.json 
  MAIN_COMMIT=$(jq -r '.values[].id?' maincommit.json) 
  #fx MAIN_COMMIT=7e01a4648fb757f98580f93a0b35af29d3dbd394 
                                                      
  echo "Get diff" 
  curl -s --negotiate --insecure -u $BITBUCKET_SERVICE_ACCOUNT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${BIT_API_URL}/projects/XXXX/repos/${file1}/compare/commits?from=${BRANCH_COMMIT}&to=${MAIN_COMMIT}" > commits.json && jq -r '.values[].properties?."jira-key"[]?' commits.json > commits.txt 
  cat        commits.txt 
  sort -u commits.txt > output.txt 
  cat output.txt         
                                                      
  while IFS= read -r line; 
   do curl -H "Authorization: Basic ${JIRA_ADMIN_TOKEN}" -X POST --data '{"body": "Hello Jira"; 
   done < output.txt         
  done 3<names.txt 4<branches.txt 
  '''
```

Comment: Can you try rephrasing and clarifying your question? What is the "top branch"? Also, I would highly suggest refactoring this code with functions so it's easier to understand the implementation logic and keep it distinct from the high-level code flow.

Comment: Well top branch are fx if the name is master, develop or what ever it is named.